# Error when the Stored procedure don't have any parameters

Tags: subsonic

I am trying to call the stored procedure using subsonic and getting `Object Reference not set`.
It is working for other procedures. It only fails if the procedure doesn't have any parameters.

Is this a known error? Is there a fix?

(I am using the latest version)

Comment: Thanks John. I will do as mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, the workaround at this time is to create a parameter for the stored procedure that doesn't do anything, I like to use an `int` and pass `0`.

This should hopefully be fixed by v3.0.

Comment: This was fixed in v2.2. Trying to track down the issue but coming up short at the moment.

Comment: Neat, why wouldn't they make this public on their website?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in version 2.2 (I can't track down the Google Code or CodePlex issue for it right now, but I'm certain it was fixed).

Comment: It was fixed in r473: http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/source/detail?r=473

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version in which this is fixed:
[Get the 2.2 version here](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/downloads/list)